# How do i filter certain items in a model field by id of another model?

Tags: python, django

This is kind of a weird question

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PostKey(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.name + " | " + self.name
```

I am trying to use the detail view such that it displays the details of the `Post` model as well as shows a list of `PostKey` (couldn't think of any other name) which has the same id as `post.id`. I have created a one to many relation with the `Post` model using `ForeignKey`.

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, DetailView
from .models import Post, PostKey

class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "test.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["posts"] = Post.objects.all()
        return context

class PostDetailView(DetailView, Post):
    template_name = "test2.html"
    model = Post
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs ):
        context = super().get_context_data( **kwargs)
        
        context['details'] = PostKey.objects.filter(id= Post.id)
        return context
```

but when I run this code it shows me something like this:

```
TypeError at /post/2
Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03F88478>.
```

I have tried to add `int(Post.id)` but it still doesn't work.

Here are is the template that is getting rendered for the above view.

```
{% for detail in details %}   
      {{detail.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem help me with this

Answer (score 2):

You filter with:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['details'] = PostKey.objects.filter(post=self.object)
    return context
```

or with:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['details'] = self.object.postkey_set.all()
    return context
```

Comment: what does self.object mean i don't get it

Comment: sorry if i am frustrating you guys, I am just a beginner developer and I get confused with so many things

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote

```
context['details'] = PostKey.objects.filter(id= Post.id)
```

does not work because `Post` is the model class, not the model instance, meaning that `Post.id` is the model field definition for the class, not the value of the `Post` instance that you are looking for; the instance in the `DetailView` is in `self.object`.

Also, you probably want to search all `PostKey` instances that have `self.object` as their parent, not those that have the same ID as the parent; you need to filter using the field `PostKey.post` (which is the ForeignKey to the parent `Post`).

---

You probably need to use the `Post` instance (in `self.object`) to filter all `PostKey` objects that have `self.object` as their parent.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = "test2.html"
    model = Post
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['details'] = PostKey.objects.filter(post=self.object)

        # or also the way @WillemVanOnsem suggested in his answer
        # context['details'] = self.object.postkey_set.all()

        return context
```

And the template code you showed seems fine:

```html
{% for det in details %}   
    {{ det.name }}
    {{ det }}          <!-- this will use method PostKey.__str__() -->
{% endfor %}
```

---

Also, why does you class inherit from `Post` (you have `class PostDetailView(DetailView, Post):`) ?
That does no seem right, it should just inherit from `DetailView` in this case.

Comment: your answer makes sense and i am going to try it out now, when nothing seemed to be working for me I just made `PostDetailView` inherit from Post to try a different approach

Comment: can you also help me with showing this in the template

Comment: @Flamiooo Your template code seems fine; iterating over `details` and displaying each detail should work with the template code that you showed.

Comment: it does work and i can finally work on the real project